# Get href value with DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Following a `file_get_contents`, I receive this HTML:

```
<h1>
    <a href="blablabla.html">Manhattan Skyline</a>
</h1>
```

I want to get the `blablabla.html` part only.

How can I parse it with `DOMDocument` feature in PHP?

Important: the HTML I receive contains more than one `<a href="...">`.

What I try is:

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://...');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);

$url = $xp->query('h1//a[@href=""]');
$url = $url->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h1//a[@href=""]` is looking for an `a` element with an `href` attribute with an empty string as the value, whereas your `href` attribute contains something other than the empty string as the value.

---

If that's the entire document, then you could use the expression `//a`.

Otherwise, `h1//a` should work as well.

If you require the `a` element to have an `href` attribute with any kind of value, you could use `h1//a[@href]`.

If the `h1` is not at the root of the document, you might want to use `//h1` instead. So the last example would become `//h1//a[@href]`.